# Is it possible to simplify this sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I need help to simplify this sum:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} ((k-1)!)^2 \left[ \binom{n}{k} - \binom{n-k}{k} \right]$$

I have tried to use Pascal's formula for the difference:
$$\binom{n}{k} - \binom{n-k}{k} = \sum_{p=1}^{k} \binom{n-p}{k-1} $$

But i didn't see anything to simplify.
Is it possible to simplify it ?

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't use Pascal's formula here. You should distribute the leading terms and expand them to see if somethings cancel out. Specifically, you can get rid of part of that nasty squared factorial. I haven't looked into this, just a look ahead that may make things simplify.

Comment: According to you, i obtained: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} ^2 ((k-1)!)^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{k} ((k-1)!)^2$$
The first sum looks like: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} ((k-1)!)$$
which can be calculate by derivative method but i have no idea with the squared expression.

Comment: have you tried expanding the binomial terms into factorials and then playing around with them?

Comment: For the first sum: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} ^2 ((k-1)!)^2 = (n!)^2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k^2 (n-k)! ^2}$$
obtained in splitting binomial terms. Is it possible to simplify that? It looks like Cauchy's product.

Comment: Sometimes with counting problem it helps to know where the problem comes from (because there may be several equivalent ways to count the same thing), could you explain where this sum comes from ?

Comment: The sum appears in my work but only after lot of calculus. There is no counting problem consideration in the work. 
I read many topics to simplify sum on mathoverflow such as: 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291738/new-binomial-coefficient-identity 
I haven't any knowledge on hypergeometric series but is it possible to use them on my cases?