# How to calculate this binomial sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

In a previous post i was asking about a complicated sum which seems not possible to simplify:
[Is it possible to simplify this sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808176/is-it-possible-to-simplify-this-sum)

I want now to calculate the simpler sum:
$$ S := \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (k-1)!$$

I have tried to use derivative method like that:
I define $f(x):= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^{k-1}$
We have:
$$ f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^{k} = \dfrac{1}{x} ( (x+1)^n -1 )$$
And the successive derivatives give:
$$f^{(1)} (x)= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (k-1) x^{k-2}$$
$$f^{(2)} (x)= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (k-1)(k-2) x^{k-3}$$... I would like to evaluate in 1 but i don't see a way to obtain the sum $S$ i want. Is it possible to simplify it (maybe with another method) ?

Thank you.

Comment: $S=\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-x}\,dx$, but not sure if it helps.

Comment: This is [OEIS A002104](https://oeis.org/A002104). There does not seem to be a nice closed form known.